# Detecting change of a variable (detect mouse clicks)

Tags: interface, gui-construction, eventhandler

I want to do something when the mouse is clicked. But it shouldn't matter where the mouse is clicked, so I can't use `EventHandler`. Instead, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0},
 WhenEvent[ControllerState["Button 1"], i = i + 1]
  i]
```

`WhenEvent` is not the right function. What I want is a function that will do something when `ControllerState["Button 1"]` switches from `false` to `true`.

Comment: Try this: `DynamicModule[{i = 0}, Dynamic[If[ControllerState["Button 1"], (i = i + 1)]; i]]`.  I think you'll find it doesn't quite behave right.  It's really more like a mouse-down event, than a mouse-click.  Perhaps that's what you want

Comment: No, it must only count one click one time. This is part of the problem.

Comment: There's no such thing as a dynamic variable. `Dynamic` only keeps some visible output up to date. So, whatever you do with `Dynamic`, in the best case scenario it will only work when it is visible. Is that what you want?

Comment: If so, you can tweak @MichaelE2's suggestion to "remember" the last check result so it is only triggered in an appropriate change of state. If the behaviour is at notebook level, you can more simply use `NotebookEventActions`, or `NotebookDynamicExpression`

Comment: Well... there will be a dynamic component to it. I will click a mouse, and it will change some variables and this will result in a graph of mouse clicks over time. It will be system wide, not on the notebook level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just working along the lines of @Rojo's comment:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0, state = False}, 
 Dynamic[If[ControllerState["Button 1"], 
   If[state, i = i + 1; state = False], If[! state, state = True]]; i]
 ]
```

Sometimes it appears that the mouse action is intercepted by *Mathematica*.  You may find that unnacceptable.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be intercepted for me. Works well, thank you.

Comment: OK, I unmarked temporarily but I'm satisfied with this solution. Will accept it later if I there isn't a way better solution.